# OPTIONS, HEAD, PATCH method in swagger-ui but not in RestController

Tags: java, spring, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm new in using Swagger I have implemented a SwaggerConfig class and one RestController.
In my RestController I have only GET, POST, PUT, DELETE implemented, but swagger generates also methods for OPTIONS and HEAD? What is the reason for that?
Are they always generated by default from Swagger? What is the reason for the generation of those methods?
Thanks in advance.

```
@RestController
public class TimesheetRequestController {


@Autowired
TimesheetRepository timeRepo;


@RequestMapping("/timesheets")
public List<Timesheet> getTimesheets() {

    List<Timesheet> results = new ArrayList<>();
    timeRepo.findAll().forEach(results::add);

    return results;
}

@PostMapping("/timesheets")
@ApiParam(type="Timesheet")
public ResponseEntity<Object> createTimesheetEntry(@RequestBody Timesheet timesheet) {

    Timesheet savedTimesheet = timeRepo.save(timesheet);

    URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}")
            .buildAndExpand(savedTimesheet.getId()).toUri();

    return ResponseEntity.created(location).build();
}

@PutMapping("/timesheets")
public ResponseEntity<Object> getTimesheetEntry(@RequestBody Timesheet timesheet, @PathVariable long id) {

    Optional<Timesheet> timesheetOptional = timeRepo.findById(id);

    if (!timesheetOptional.isPresent())
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();

    timesheet.setId(id);

    timeRepo.save(timesheet);

    return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();

}

@GetMapping("/timesheets/{id}")
public Timesheet getTimesheetEntry(@PathVariable long id) {

    Optional<Timesheet> timesheet = timeRepo.findById(id);

    if (!timesheet.isPresent())
        throw new TimesheetNotFoundException("id-" + id);

    return timesheet.get();

}

@DeleteMapping("/timesheets/{id}")
public void deleteTimesheetEntry(@PathVariable long id) {
    timeRepo.deleteById(id);

}



}
```

[image: Swagger UI]

Here my Swagger config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("package_name"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your function like this.

```
@RequestMapping(path="/timesheets",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Timesheet> getTimesheets() {

    List<Timesheet> results = new ArrayList<>();
    timeRepo.findAll().forEach(results::add);

    return results;
}
```

or even change it to `@GetMapping("/timesheets")`

This one is similar to this [issue](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1447).

Comment: Changed it to GetMapping and now it works. Thnaks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Although it's called REST which refers for the 4 basic operations, HEAD and OPTIONS methods are also commonly used by REST clients. So Swagger automatically lists the controller methods handling these http methods too.

And because you haven't define any method parameter for this controller method:

```
@RequestMapping("/timesheets")
public List<Timesheet> getTimesheets() {

    List<Timesheet> results = new ArrayList<>();
    timeRepo.findAll().forEach(results::add);

    return results;
}
```

... all of the requests which are not taken by any other controller methods (because of stricter matching parameters) will be redirected here. So Swagger will list them.

If you don't want to allow HEAD and OPTIONS then change `@RequestMapping("/timesheets")` to `@GetMapping("/timesheets")`